# Facing Android layout height issue

Tags: android, layout

I have one edittext and one textview in my linear layout and I gave same height to both, But still getting height difference.

[image]

here my xml. Please suggest me what am I doing wrong here ?

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="10">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblKayitNo"
                style="@style/NoviLabel"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="Kayıt No" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtKayitNo"
                style="@style/DefaultEditTextSmall"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

***Style Files***

```
<style name="NoviLabel">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-small</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/novitextview_border</item>
</style>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: remove the marginTop in the root LinearLayout

Comment: remove gravity left...

Comment: @LucaZiegler i tried ur suggestions and result isthe same..

Comment: @RickyPatel i tried ur suggestions and result isthe same..

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblKayitNo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                style="@style/NoviLabel"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="Kayıt No"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtKayitNo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                style="@style/DefaultEditTextSmall"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think so.. but if i remove the style from items, its keep the same high problem. i already tried to remove style from editview and textview...

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblKayitNo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:text="Kayıt No" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtKayitNo"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I think you use `android:layout_weight="4"` for Textview and `android:layout_weight="6"` foe EditText thats why this problem occure. so take same weight for both.

Comment: weight doesnt effect only width ?

Comment: your novitextview_border is creating the problem i think

Comment: if i remove style result is not changing dude :( already tried

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="center_vertical"` for LinearLayout

Comment: are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the     `android:layout_weight=` to be equal for both fields.

> The layout_weight attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen

from the Android Developers Ref here: [link] http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"        
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblKayitNo"
            style="@style/NoviLabel"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:text="Kayıt No" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtKayitNo"

            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:enabled="false"
            style="@style/DefaultEditTextSmall"
            android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You have to check the style attribute, by hiding style no problem in your code

Comment: i tried ur suggestions and result isthe same..Also if i remove style result is same dude.

Comment: @keikoman But in my side if i run this on my android studio, no problem is there.....

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblKayitNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Kayıt No" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtKayitNo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Try this hope it may help